# Jasper Reports Exporting To .PDF File

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm getting a problem in the end the execution of Jasper Reports, when I try to export it. The others thinks seems to be OK.

It seems to be in the exporting time

**That's my code:**

```
JasperReport jasperReport = null;
try {
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
            .compileReport("/home/ederson/Developer/temp/StyledTextReport/StyledTextReport.jrxml");
} catch (JRException e) {
    System.err.println("Erro ao tentar compilar Jasper Report" + e);
}

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

JRDataSource dataSource = new JREmptyDataSource();

JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
try {

    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("output" + ".jasper", map, dataSource);
} catch (JRException e) {
    System.err.println("Erro ao tirar o print" + e);
}

File output = new File("/home/ederson/Developer/temp/output");
output.mkdirs();

// PDF Exportor.
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);

try {
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, new FileOutputStream("output" + ".pdf"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    System.err.println("Erro ao exportar");
} // your output goes here

exporter.exportReport();

System.out.print("Done!");
```

**That's my strack trace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No input source supplied to the exporter.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractExporter.setInput(JRAbstractExporter.java:845)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:259)
    at br.com.jReport.Run.main(Run.java:58)
```

Comment: As per the error message, you do not specify the source the way it should be. I usually use the `JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf*()` convenience methods...

Comment: @EdersonJR You can look at [Export to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jasper-reports/4190/export-to-pdf#t=201708291450303071749) or at samples from *JasperReports* distribution package

Comment: I already tried, but SimpleExporterInput class and others from the same package it's deprecated...

Comment: `JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT` is deprecated and replaced with `SimpleExporterInput`. You can check all deprecated classes [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/deprecated-list.html)